# Do individual microservices in an orchestration interact with each other?

Tags: microservices

My product is migrating to microservices and they have presented an architecture where there are 2 parts:

1. Micro App : This is UI + an Orchestration layer.
2. Microservices : The individual microservices that micro app interacts with.

Now, in this architecture, they said that the individual microservices can interact with each other directly despite the presence of the orchestration layer. This is contrary to what I read (and understood). My understanding is that individual microservices  don't interact with each other directly if there is an orchestrator. Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 0):

> My understanding is that individual microservices don't interact with each other directly if there is an orchestrator. Is my understanding correct?

Yes, you are correct.

In orchestration, by definition, there is a central brain that do the all the communication between microservices. The idea is that individual microservices do not know of each other, so how can they interact with each other?

For more information you can read [this book](https://www.amazon.co.uk/d/Books/Building-Microservices-Sam-Newman/1491950358), page 43.